# iOS pod install gcm and pnchartswift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, google-cloud-messaging

I use PNChartSwift and GCM in my Project .
I need use "use_frameworks!" for PNChartSwift in PodFile so for GCM i must not use "use_frameworks!" in PodFile

How will i use gcm ?

Log error "pod install"

```
Using PNChartSwift (0.0.2)
Using STZPopupView (1.0.1)
[!] The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/Sina/Desktop/MyShatelIOS/MyShatel/Pods/GGLInstanceID/Libraries/libGGLInstanceIDLib.a, /Users/Sina/Desktop/MyShatelIOS/MyShatel/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCloudMessaging.a, /Users/Sina/Desktop/MyShatelIOS/MyShatel/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a, /Users/Sina/Desktop/MyShatelIOS/MyShatel/Pods/GoogleCloudMessa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to mix static and dynamic libraries, it's all-or-nothing.

Instead I will suggest you to make use of of the original Obj-C version  [PNChart](https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart), which would solve your issue using GCM.

That means your podfile would look similar to the following:

```
pod "PNChart"
pod "Google/CloudMessaging"
```

The only thing you have to do differently when importing the `PNChart` is to add a briding header importing these libraries. This will make them available anywhere in the code. It would look something like the following:

```
#import <PNChart.h>
#import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>
```

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Answered OP's question about how to identify static/dynamic.

---

As a rule of thumb:

- All dependencies written in Swift are dynamic frameworks.
- All dependencies written in Obj-C are static libraries.

Apple doesn't let you build static libraries that contain Swift, so the first statement will always be true. The second statement is a bit more complicated, since Apple has previously built a lot of dynamic internal frameworks in Obj-C. This possibility has not been available to third-party developers until iOS 8 (same time as Swift was released), so don't expect any new frameworks written in Obj-C to be dynamic since they might as well be written in Swift.

Right now we are simply in a stage of "limbo" when switching between the two languages. In 1-2 years then hopefully the majority of all third-party dependencies will be written in Swift and we don't have to worry about things like static/dyanmic.

If you are interested, then you can read more about it on [the official CocoaPods blog post for release 0.36](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/).

Comment: I can imagine that this will create problems for you if you are also using `STZPopupView`. I will suggest looking into `UIPresentationController` which is a new class from iOS 8 which helps to create popovers. There is a nice tutorial about it here: http://dativestudios.com/blog/2014/06/29/presentation-controllers/

Comment: is gcm a dynamic lib ? how do i recognize dynamic or static lib ?