# Getting GoogleAnalytics CocoaPod to work in a Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

I have a Swift project and have included some Swift CocoaPods to it and it works well. However, now I want to add the `GoogleAnalytics` pod which doesn't have a Swift version but only support Objective-C, this is how my Podfile looks like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'                                  
platform :ios, '8.0'                                                             
use_frameworks!                                                                  

target 'MyApp' do                                                             
  pod 'MEViewExtensions', '~> 0.2'                                               
  pod 'SwiftColors', '~> 0.2'                                                    
  pod 'GradientView', '~> 2.0'                                                   
  pod 'GoogleAnalytics', '~> 3.12'                                               
end
```

After installing the pods, `GoogleAnalytics` does not get it's own framework in the Pods project like the others. I've tried to import it though like a framework, like this:

```
import GoogleAnalytics
```

It doesn't work. I've also tried a bridging header like this:

```
#ifndef MyApp_Bridging_Header_h
#define MyApp_Bridging_Header_h

#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>

#endif
```

It doesn't work either. Can anybody help?

Comment: Try to see my previous answer to a similar post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31227189/ios-pod-install-gcm-and-pnchartswift/31230681#31230681

Comment: Ok. So basically the answer is that i's impossible right now?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Either Google has to update their library to support dynamic libraries (I think Parse supports both) or CocoaPods has to do some smart fix. And it is simply because we are in this "limbo" state. Hopefully it'll be over in a few months :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There now exists a Swift version of Google Analytics. I've used it in a couple of projects:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.3'
```